# Change default colors in f90-mode

Tags: colors

Could you let me know where the default colors in f90-mode are defined and how to change them?

Comment: Colors or faces? I'm guessing you might mean the latter. In that case, `M-x list-faces-display` might help. If not, `M-x list-colors-display` might help.

Comment: Thank you. Specifically, I'd like to change the color of PROGRAM or SUBROUTINE name from the current blueish color to, say, yellow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change color of Python "None" and Booleans for digital-ofs1 color theme](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53766/how-to-change-color-of-python-none-and-booleans-for-digital-ofs1-color-theme)

Comment: Yes, my question was answered by that. Thank you!